# Изменить размер канваса без потери качества

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Делаю фоторедактор на canvas. Я хочу чтобы пользователь загрузил свою картинку, после чего создался бы канвас равный размеру загруженной картинки. Но проблема в том, что окно моего приложения 900 на 600 пикселей, а картинка может быть и намного больше.

Как сделать так, чтоб загружаемое изображение масштабировалось до нужного мне размера и не вылазило за края приложения, но после нужных мне манипуляций сохранялось в размере, который был изначально.

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы решил проблему.
Просто через css масштабировал холст, сохраняется в исходном размере. Пока проблем в таком решении не выявил.

```
                    var canvas_scale = document.getElementById("canvas");
                        canvas_scale.style.MozTransform = 'scale(0.5)';
                        canvas_scale.style.WebkitTransform = 'scale(0.5)';
                        canvas_scale.style.OTransform = 'scale(0.5)';
                        canvas_scale.style.MsTransform = 'scale(0.5)';
                        canvas_scale.style.transform = 'scale(0.5)';
```